# verify whitespace in a string

Tags: php, regex, string, strstr

I have an issue with a string:

```
$string = 'Hello<a href="#">there</a>, how are <a href="#">you</a>? I am<a href="#">good</a>'?
```

I would like to automatically detect there is no whitespace between the  tag and the character before, and add a whitespace if it is not available and change it to:

```
$string = 'Hello <a href="#">there</a>, how are <a href="#">you</a>? I am <a href="#">good</a>'?
```

Using PHP, regular expression? or strtr?

Likewise, for the closing, can we check it will add a whitespace if it isn't exist btw another character meanwhile ignore if it is .,?!;:

```
</a>next -> </a> next (whitespace added)
</a>! -> </a>! (Unchanged)
```

Comment: I have added scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~(?<! )(?=<a)|(?<=</a>)(?![ .,?!;:])~', ' ', $yourstring);
```

**Explanation**

- On each side of the alternation `|`, we look for a potential position where a space should be inserted, without matching any actual characters
- On the left, the negative lookbehind `(?<! )` asserts that what precedes the current position is not a space, and the lookahead `(?=<a)` asserts that what follows is `<a`
- On the right, the lookbehind `(?<=</a>)` asserts that what precedes is `</a>`, and the negative lookahead `(?! )` asserts that what follows is not one of these chars: `.,?!;:`
- we replace the position of the match with  (inserting a space)

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Like wise, for the closing, can we check it will add a whitespace if it isn't exist btw another character meanwhile ignore if it is .,?!;: Please check the bottom of updated question. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing, it seems it didn't ignore .,!?;; Can you amend it to accommodate that there'll be NO whitespace it the next character is .,?!;: Thanks.

Comment: I hadn't understood that requirement. Done.

Answer (score 0):

`$newString = str_replace(" <", "<", $string);`

or more specifically

`$newString = str_replace(" <a", "<a", $string);`